# what are these sleeping process?

Tags: mysql, innodb

i've been having high cpu usage by mysql

so when i did `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`

i got this :

```
User                Host        db         Command  Time    State                   Info
 sitedb_main     localhost   sitedb_main     Sleep   72      NULL
 sitedb_main     localhost   sitedb_main     Query   0      Copying to tmp table     SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE `confirm` = 1   AND `...
 sitedb_main     localhost   NULL            Query   0       NULL                    SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

another one :

```
Id      User                Host        db         Command  Time    State           Info
209521  sitedb_main     localhost   sitedb_main     Sleep   108                     NULL
209752  sitedb_main     localhost   sitedb_main     Sleep   0                       NULL
209756  sitedb_main     localhost   sitedb_main     Query   0     Sorting result    SELECT *    FROM (`images`)    WHERE `confirm` =  1
209757  sitedb_main     localhost   NULL            Query   0     NULL              SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

there is one particulars process which has sleep under the Command column , it starts at 0 for time and goes up to 100 or 200 sometimes 300 and then fades away .

it seems that mysql load peaks when couple of these sleep process (5-6) are running simultaneously

i've no idea what are these sleeping processes (nothing under the info column )

Comment: I think this question is more suitable for serverfault.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com is a better fit actually

Comment: Unclosed sessions, kept by shell script or by application if it uses connection pool.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski i've tried dba and serverfault first , no answer

Comment: @ravnur are you talking about php session ? is there any article or reading material about this issue  ?